# Why can't I use PowerShell's Start-Process with both -Credential and -Verb parameters?

Tags: powershell

Using `powershell.exe`, I want to emulate `cmd.exe`'s `runas` command with the additional benefit of escalating privileges through UAC.

However, if I both supply both `-Credential` and `-Verb Runas` parameters to `Start-Process`, I get the error below:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'username',(ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force)) -ArgumentList '-NoProfile' -Verb RunAs

Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Using only one of these parameters yields no errors:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoProfile"
```

Why is that? Both syntax forms of `Start-Process` accept `[<CommonParameters>]`, which `-Verb Runas` belongs to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-Verb` parameter is only available in one of the parameter sets (if you do `Get-Help Start-Process` you can see it explictly listed in the second set):

```
SYNTAX
    Start-Process [-FilePath] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <String[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError <String>] [-RedirectStandardInput <String>] [-RedirectStandardOutput <String>] [-UseNewEnvironment] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-WorkingDirectory <String>]
    [<CommonParameters>]

    Start-Process [-FilePath] <String> [[-ArgumentList] <String[]>] [-PassThru] [-Verb <String>] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-WorkingDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

It's not a part of `CommonParameters`, that just includes things like `-Debug`, `-Verbose`, `-ErrorAction` etc. (see the full list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6)).

This seems to be a possible workaround:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential mydomain\myuser -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process powershell -verb runas}'
```

Comment: Thank you, can you think of any reason why not having `-Verb Runas` in the first parameter set?

Comment: No i'm not certain, could just be an oversight when they developed the cmdlet. The internet suggests this workaround: `Start-Process powershell -Credential mydomain\mydomainAdmin -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process notepad -verb runas}'`